# How to store dates in a List<DateTime> in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am trying to use a `PageView.builder` in my application and i wanted each page to display a particular date. I have defined a list of type `DateTime` : `List<DateTime> _month;`. how do i store all the days in a particular month (30 days) in the list `_month`?

The stored dates must be of type `DateTime` in order to implement this in my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will do what you need. I don't know the entire structure of your code so I just wrote this example!

```
void main() {
  int month = 1;
  DateTime start = DateTime(2019,month);
  DateTime end = DateTime(2019,month+1);
  int c = (end.toUtc().difference(start.toUtc()).inDays);
  List<DateTime> _month = [];
  _month.addAll(List.generate(c,(index) => start.toUtc().add(Duration(days:index)).toLocal()));

  print(_month);

}
```